# How to fade the activity when slider menu opened in andorid?

Tags: android, slidingmenu, slidingdrawer

I am using this library [Sliding menu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu) . But its is not fading the main view when the slider opened. I want the above view got faded when the sliding menu is opened.

```
SlidingMenu sm = getSlidingMenu();
        sm.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
        sm.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
        sm.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
    //  sm.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);

        sm.setFadeEnabled(true);
        sm.setFadeDegree(0.5f);
        sm.setBehindWidth(500);

        sm.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Use **transparent Framelayout** that will be on top of your activity and **will be hidden**

2.when **slider opens make it visible**.

Comment: But this is the default property of slider menu. Why make it manually?

Comment: it is not default you might seen so many customized slider menu this is one of them if you want to achieve you will have to follow this

Comment: I will try, but i think there must be some option. Because in the navigation drawer that android provide has this property by default.

Comment: any body got solution ?